# Wait until thread finishes gracefully

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I have this code:

```
public class JsoupParser {      
    ArrayList<CompanyInfo> arr = new ArrayList<CompanyInfo>();

    public JsoupParser() {}

    public ArrayList<CompanyInfo> parse(final String link) throws IOException {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Here I do some operations and then assign some value
                // to my `arr` ArrayList
            }
        };
        new Thread(runnable).start();

        return arr; // error here, as expected      
    }
}
```

System immediately returns `arr`, which at that point is `null`.

How can I return `arr` only after `Thread` finishes? How can I be informed, that `Thread` has finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I return arr only after Thread finishes? How can I be
>   informed, that Thread has finished?

```
Thread parseThread = new Thread(runnable).start();

parseThread.join();

return arr;
```

There's the literal answer to your question but zmbq's answer is more fitting for what you're after.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of using another thread, is to have it run while your main thread does something else. If you want your `parse` method to return the array when it's done, it shouldn't start another thread.

However, since I suppose you *do* want the calculation to take place in the background, you need to do something else. Why don't you take a look at [AsyncTask](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html)? It is probably what you need.